# PHP foreach in foreach loop to Twig

Tags: php, symfony, foreach, twig

I use the following code for foreach in PHP:

```
$fruit = array();

$fruit[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Banana 1');
$fruit[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Pear 1');
$fruit[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Mango 1');

$fruit[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Banana 2');
$fruit[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Pear 2');
$fruit[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mango 2');

function get_pieces($id)
{
    $pieces = array();

    switch ($id)
    {
        case 1:
            $pieces[] = array('number' => 1);
            $pieces[] = array('number' => 2);
        break;

        case 2:
            $pieces[] = array('number' => 3);
            $pieces[] = array('number' => 4, 'qwerty' => 1);        
        break;
    }

    return $pieces;
}

foreach ($fruit as $item)
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<b>' . $item['name'] . '</b>';

    $pieces = get_pieces($item['id']);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece)
    {
        echo '<p>';
        echo '<i>' . $piece['number'] . '</i>';

        if (isset($piece['qwerty']))
        {
            echo ' => <i>qwerty is on</i>';
        }

        echo '</p>';
    }

    echo '</p>';
}
```

I want to get this into a Twig template. For the fruit array only, I have no problems, but the pieces part, gives only the results of case 2 in Twig. Here you see the current code I use:

```
$render = array();

$render = array_merge($render, array('fruit' => $fruit));
$render = array_merge($render, array('pieces' => get_pieces(1)));

$render = array_merge($render, array('fruit' => $fruit));
$render = array_merge($render, array('pieces' => get_pieces(2)));

echo $twig->render('test.html', $render);

{% for f in fruit %}
    <p>{{ f.id }}</p>
    <p>{{ f.name }}</p>
    {% for p in pieces %}
        <p>Piece {{ p.number }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can someone help me, to get this second pieces array also correct working in Twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `array_merge_recursive` when merging the `pieces` array, as `array_merge` will override the keys from the previous array.

The *same keys* are used within both cases, i.e `0` and `1`. `array_merge_recursive` creates new `keys`.

https://3v4l.org/RBZDo

---

### Updated

Attach the pieces to each piece of fruit instead, and pull that out of the array.

```
$fruit = array();

$fruit[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Banana 1', 'pieces' => get_pieces(1));
$fruit[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Pear 1', 'pieces' => get_pieces(1));
$fruit[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Mango 1', 'pieces' => get_pieces(1));

$fruit[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Banana 2', 'pieces' => get_pieces(2));
$fruit[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Pear 2', 'pieces' => get_pieces(2));
$fruit[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mango 2', 'pieces' => get_pieces(2));

// ...

echo $twig->render('test.html', array('fruit' => $fruit));

{% for f in fruit %}
    <p>{{ f.id }}</p>
    <p>{{ f.name }}</p>
    {% for p in f.pieces %}
        <p>Piece {{ p.number }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Results:

PHP: https://3v4l.org/kUKff 
Twig: https://twigfiddle.com/p2hqsr

Comment: Have you clicked the link? The pieces part contains 4 elements: https://3v4l.org/RBZDo

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Only show the pieces part for the given fruit?

Comment: Ah ok, you're better attach the pieces to the fruit array, then pull that out with twig. I'll update my answer shortly.